# Facing issue while loading from one angular project to another angular project through script

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two angular projects like project1 which is angular6 version and project2 which is angular4 version. I am trying to load  project2 from  project1 through script. While calling through script getting following error in console:

> inline.6412abaf43654c74363d.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: n is not a
>   function at window.webpackJsonp
>   (inline.6412abaf43654c74363d.bundle.js:1) at
>   polyfills.0e96727dab9e2340b6b0.bundle.js:1